# Samba public share does not show up at "Network" in Windows, but is accessible

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, samba

I have set up a Samba public share as follows:

```
[global]
    workgroup = MYWORKGROUP
    netbios name = SHUTTLESERVER
    security = user
    map to guest = bad user
    dns proxy = no
    guest account = nobody

    #to disable printer sharing error message
    printing = bsd
    printcap name = /dev/null

[public]
    comment = Public Share
    path = /home/villermen/public
    browsable = yes
    writable = yes
    guest only = yes
```

The share can be accessed and written to just fine by Windows using the server's name or ip, (\192.168.something or \SHUTTLESERVER). However, it does not show up in the list of network devices. My laptop on the same workgroup, and some other devices like my printer/router show up just fine. The server shows up as dlna device too if I install minidlna, no idea if that is of any use to the question though.

I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04.3, and Samba 4.1.6-Ubuntu.

Would be great if someone shed some light on this, as I've tried pretty much every option to get this to work.

Gr.Viller

Comment: Same problem here, but only affects certain random folders

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found the reason it was not showing up. After changing the workgroup to something arbitrary to both the server and my pc it got detected. Turns out there was already a device on the same network with the name of the workgroup, which was making it conflict in one way or another. Removing the device's lease from my router's dhcp table made the server appear on the workgroup in question.